# Radio Button Selection Detected by a Divison

Tags: html

Suppose i have two radio buttons

```
    <input id="Individual User" type="radio" name="register_form_categories" value="Individual User" />
    <label for="Individual User">Individual User</label>

    <input id="Group Admin" type="radio" name="register_form_categories" value="Group Admin" />
    <label for="Group Admin">Group Admin</label>
```

Now i have a Next divison also

```
<a href="#"><div class="sign_in_me">Next</div></a>
```

How to open different servlets let individual.html and group.html on different radio button click followed by next click.

Please help

Comment: can you elaborate? the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @andrew i want if i select first radio button and then click on next button it should open individual.html but if i select second radio button then it should open group.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following 
http://jsfiddle.net/Hz3LZ/

```
$(docukment).ready(function(){
    if( $("input[name='register_form_categories']:checked")){
      changeLink($("input[name='register_form_categories']:checked").val());
     }
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
      changeLink($(this).val());
    })

 })

function changeLink(value){
var arr =value.split(' ');
//the above will take the value of the checked radio
//and split it on space. This will give you an array that contains 2 strings.
//If you check Group Admin, then you have arr[0]='Group' and arr[1]='Admin'
   $('#a-next').attr('href',arr[0].toLowerCase()+'.html');
}
```

Comment: @DimtrisKontoulis where u had redirected it to page individudal.html?am not getiing the meaning of while $('#a-next').attr('href',arr[0].toLowerCase()+'.html');

Comment: Also where you had called the function you made ?

Comment: I added comments to the code above. Do you understand Javascript?